# Javascript - 2 var input in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

I need my two elements to go into my var busList like this (this is hardcoded):

```
var busList = [
{ RuteNr: '901', RuteNavn: 'Vejle - Kolding'},
{ RuteNr: '901-xs', RuteNavn: 'Kolding - Vejle'},
{ RuteNr: '401', RuteNavn: 'Kastrup - arhus'}];
```

But in the actual code, I am receiving it all in a list. Therefore I am doing it this way:

```
    rutenr = data.busliste[counter].RuteNr; //this line works fine
    rutenavn = data.busliste[counter].RuteNavn; //this line works fine
    var busList = [{ RuteNr: rutenr , RuteNavn: rutenavn}];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The elements does not go into the array. 
Any help?

EDIT: (complete code)

```
 $.get('http://localhost:7120/LocationService/GetRouteList', function(data) {
 $('.result').html(data);
 var counter = 0;
 for (var i in data.busliste)
 {
    rutenr = data.busliste[counter].RuteNr;
    rutenavn = data.busliste[counter].RuteNavn;
    busList.push({ RuteNr: rutenr , RuteNavn: rutenavn});
     counter++;
 }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to put it in to but havea look at Array.push() that should do what you are trying ?

Comment: What does your original list look like, and are you pushing onto `busList`?

Comment: Please write precisely: the input you get, and the output you want to get for that input.

Comment: I'm my actual code (not the hardcoded) - I get absolutely nothing in the array. 
The other hardcoded one obviously works.

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: you might be getting some error in your developer console of the browser,. check let me know. othewise syntax wise its ok

Comment: Complete method edited in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a array first (before the `counter` loop)

```
busList = [];
```

Then in the `counter` loop

```
rutenr = data.busliste[counter].RuteNr;
rutenavn = data.busliste[counter].RuteNavn;
busList.push({ RuteNr: rutenr , RuteNavn: rutenavn});
```

Update:

```
$.get('http://localhost:7120/LocationService/GetRouteList', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    busList = [];
    $.each(data.busliste, function(i, v) {
                busList.push({
                            RuteNr : v.RuteNr,
                            RuteNavn : v.RuteNavn
                        });
            });
    console.log(busList)
});
```

Comment: yeah          he is right. The console would have shown you "ReferenceError: busList is not defined"

Comment: This seems to have solved half of the problem! (Gave point for useful answer). But it doesn't go further down in the code (outside my loop), it gets empty again. 
In loop this works: alert(busList[2].RuteNr).. 

Outside loop, it's empty.

Note: busList is defined outside the method.

Comment: @dinosaur remove the `var` before `busList = [];`, because I assume what you want is a global variable